# astrojs/image works locally but not on Vercel

Tags: javascript, image, vite, astrojs, static-site-generation

None of my local images are working, except when using the background property. Here's the astro component

```
---
import { Image } from '@astrojs/image/components';
import CTA from './common/CTA.astro';

export const prerender = true;
const IMAGE_SIZE = 500;
---

<div
  class="relative bg-[url('/images/salon.jpg')] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
>
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-black/75"></div>
  <Image
    src={import('~/assets/images/homepage-logo.png')}
    class="animation"
    width={IMAGE_SIZE}
    height={IMAGE_SIZE}
    aspectRatio="16:9"
    alt="Barber Studio"
    format="png"
  />
  <h1 class="hidden">Barber Studio</h1>
  <div
    data-delay={500}
    data-animation="fade-in"
    class="animation relative w-full z-1 text-center -translate-y-11 opacity-0"
  >
    <CTA dark />
  </div>
</div>
```

So in this case, the background image is set correctly, but Image component is giving an error in production, deployed on Vercel: `https://barberstudio-jet.vercel.app/_image?f=png&w=500&h=500&href=%2F_astro%2Fhomepage-logo.183ae1e9.png`

You can check the website here: https://barberstudio-jet.vercel.app/

I've searched a lot online and this seems to be a known issue, but none of the solutions worked. I'm using this template: https://astro.build/themes/details/astroship/
so you can check the package.json.

I've changed to node 16 both in Vercel and locally, I've tried many different imports from Astro docs and I've `serviceEntryPoint: '@astrojs/image/sharp'` in astro.config file, but none worked.

Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it all, the problem was related to Vercel. Still didn't figure out the issue. But for now, the solution was simple: deploy on Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, images using the built in Astro  component working fine on dev but 404ing on when deployed on Vercel.

I found the answer in the Astro Vercel [config guide](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vercel/#imageservice), you need to enable the Vercel imageService in `astro.config.mjs` ;

```
  adapter: vercel({
    imageService: true,
  }),
```

The Vercel guide on Astro images do point out that it only supports static and serverless.

[image: Vercel Astro note on static and serverless]